# SQL cartesian product turns

Tags: sql, select

I am trying to understand the cartesian product with the `SELECT` command
but when I try different combinations I get different results like when I type

```
select X.A,Y.A,Z.A
From X,Y,Z
```

i get XxYxZ

but if i try

```
select X.A,Y.A,Z.A
From X,Y,Z  
where (conditions)
```

depending on how I put the conditions also I get more different combinations

Comment: Please explain your problem a bit more, add sample data and expected output. And please, please, use punctuation!

Comment: SQL 101: if there is no `ORDER BY` clause, the server is free to return rows in any order it likes.

Comment: They are different queries so you'll get different results, and as already mentioned, without an order by there is no guaranteed order

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the database you are using, you want to fiddle with `cross join`.

Also, the results vary depending on data, to achieve persistent order you want to use `order by` clause.